# Determine the area bounded by the curves $y=2x$ and $y=x^2$ and the parabaloid $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

> Determine the area bounded by the curves $y=2x$ and $y=x^2$ and the parabaloid $z=x^2+y^2$

I'm not really sure what my function that I'm integrating is supposed to be I believe I want to integrate on the set $S=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 2, 0\leq y\leq 4\}$?

and evalute $\int\int_S x^2+y^2 dA$?

In which case I evaluated this to be $8\frac{20}{3}$.

Comment: I'm having trouble reading that problem statement. Do they mean volume, rather than area (and in that case, surface rather than curve)? That's the interpretation you've gone for. Or do they mean the surface area of the paraboloid determined by those two curves? Or something else? I have no idea.

Comment: If it's volume, $$S=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 4, x^2\leq y\leq 2x\}.$$
You have have more success if you think about this as a double integral
$$\int_{x=0}^4\int_{y=x^2}^{2x}(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall how did you get the bounds you have there? I took the integral $\int_0^2\int_0^4 x^2+y^2 dxdy$ as the points of intersection of those curves is $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$.

Comment: You're right, I should have put 2 as the upper bound on $x$. But the bounds on $y$ definitely aren't just rectangular. [Try a diagram.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wofyv8y2bk) At a given $x$ value, $y$ does not vary from $0$ to $4$, it varies from $x^2$ to $2x$ (a smaller region).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2x=x^2 $ then $x=0,2$.
We know that : $2x>x^2$ for $x\in[0,2]$ so :

$$Area=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{2x}x^2+y^2dydx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{14}{3}x^3-x^4-\frac{1}{3}x^6dx=\frac{56}{3}-\frac{32}{5}-\frac{128}{21}$$